# async - one task invokes several concurrent tasks

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have an async function using websocket to subscribe stock price.
I would like to run my own algorithm once I get an updated price.

```
async def subscribewebsite():
  while true:
     get_price_from_website()

     if price is updated:
        await decidebuyorsell(price)

async def decidebuyorsell(price):
    sleep(3)
    xxxx
```

My question is, decidebuyorsell may take several seconds. I don't want to wait until it finished. I need to keep watching stock price in case there is a change. e.g, if the stock price is updated, a decidebuyorsell "thread" will start to run. and the subscribewebsite doesn't have to wait.
Is it possible to run several decidebuyorsells concurrently? How to orginize the code? Thanks

Comment: have the price be dropped into a queue and have your coro pick up the item from the queue and process it. does that make sense?

Comment: can you explain more about this? Based on this case, how should I rearrange the code?

Comment: Replace `await decidebuyorsell(price)` with `asyncio.create_task(decidebuyorsell(price))` and it will run in the background. Also, I assume that you're awaiting `get_price_from_website()` as well?